# django call multiple models

Tags: python, django

i'm study bioinformatics

i want to make django DataBase

i already know make model, it has three columns.

i Meet a big huddle making models

my db has too many columns(about 700)

```
from django.db import models

class CMS(models.Model):
   class Meta:
      db_table = 'CMS' 
   AT1G01560.3   = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
   AT1G01560.2   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   AT1G01610.1   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   AT1G01720.1   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       .                       .              
       .                       .
       .                       .              
       .                       .
       .                       .              
       .                       .
   AT5G66280.1   = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I could not write all 700

then, i call DataFrame and i use DataFrame.columns

```
import pandas as pd
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class CMS(models.Model):
   class Meta:
      db_table = 'cms'
   df=pd.read_csv('UDUBBBBBBBBBBB.csv',sep='\t')
   db_columns=df.columns 

   for xx in df.columns:
    k= models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    exec("%s=%s"%(xx,k))
```

but its has error

```
    target_id,AT1G01560.3,AT1G01560.2,AT1G01610.1,AT1G01720.1,AT1G02110.1,AT1G02220.1,AT1G02230.1,AT1G02440.1,AT1G02450.1,AT1G03430.1,AT1G03850.3,AT1G03850.2,AT1G06000.1,AT1G06160.1,AT1G06620.1,AT1G06620.2,AT1G06640.1,AT1G06640.3,AT1G06640.2,AT1G06980.1,AT1G07630.1,AT1G08050.1,AT1G09310.1,AT1G09630.1,AT1G09750.1,AT1G10417.4,AT1G11310.3,AT1G11440.1,AT1G11580.1,AT1G11700.1,AT1G12010.1,AT1G12240.1,AT1G13470.1,AT1G13540.1,AT1G13550.1,AT1G14120.3,AT1G14130.1,AT1G14250.1,AT1G14700.2,AT1G16670.1,AT1G17380.2,AT1G17380.3,AT1G17840.1,AT1G18650.1,AT1G19180.3,AT1G19300.1,AT1G19550.1,AT1G19570.1,AT1G19670.1,AT1G20190.1,AT1G21130.2,AT1G23050.1,AT1G23330.1,AT1G23830.1,AT1G23840.1,AT1G23850.1,AT1G24070.1,AT1G24070.2,AT1G24145.1,AT1G25230.1,AT1G28480.1,AT1G28510.1,AT1G28600.1,AT1G29330.1,AT1G29430.1,AT1G29440.1,AT1G29450.2,AT1G29500.1,AT1G29510.1,AT1G29660.1,AT1G29670.1,AT1G30900.1,AT1G31550.1,AT1G31550.2,AT1G32640.1,AT1G32690.1,AT1G33612.1,AT1G34750.1,AT1G34750.4,AT1G43160.1,AT1G43310.1,AT1G44790.1,AT1G45145.1,AT1G45201.1,AT1G47840.1,AT1G49320.1,AT1G49490.1,AT1G51760.1,AT1G51780.1,AT1G51860.2,AT1G52030.1,AT1G52190.1,AT1G52400.1,AT1G52400.2,AT1G52410.2,AT1G52410.1,AT1G52720.1,AT1G53250.1,AT1G53885.1,AT1G53903.1,AT1G54010.1,AT1G54020.2,AT1G54030.2,AT1G54040.3,AT1G54740.1,AT1G55910.1,AT1G56020.1,AT1G58300.1,AT1G60260.1,AT1G60800.2,AT1G61065.1,AT1G61120.1,AT1G61610.1,AT1G62520.1,AT1G62660.1,AT1G62660.4,AT1G64200.2,AT1G64200.1,AT1G64710.1,AT1G64710.2,AT1G65890.1,AT1G66100.1,AT1G66880.3,AT1G67330.1,AT1G67590.1,AT1G67750.1,AT1G68190.1,AT1G68330.1,AT1G68780.1,AT1G69370.1,AT1G69520.1,AT1G69610.1,AT1G70690.1,AT1G70700.1,AT1G70700.3,AT1G70700.2,AT1G71040.1,AT1G71100.1,AT1G72120.1,AT1G72450.2,AT1G72645.1,AT1G72730.1,AT1G72900.1,AT1G72920.1,AT1G73325.1,AT1G73500.1,AT1G73805.1,AT1G73830.1,AT1G74950.2,AT1G74950.1,AT1G75220.1,AT1G75250.2,AT1G75990.1,AT1G77420.1,AT1G77450.1,AT1G77520.1,AT1G77885.1,AT1G78170.1,AT1G78270.1,AT1G78450.1,AT1G78490.1,AT1G78550.1,AT1G78560.1,AT1G78660.3,AT1G78660.2,AT1G79310.1,AT1G79380.1,AT1G79760.1,AT1G80510.1,AT1G80610.1,AT2G02310.1,AT2G02800.2,AT2G02800.1,AT2G03980.3,AT2G04515.1,AT2G05260.1,AT2G05310.2,AT2G06255.1,AT2G10940.2,AT2G13790.1,AT2G14560.3,AT2G15090.1,AT2G17120.1,AT2G20340.1,AT2G21900.1,AT2G22200.1,AT2G22770.1,AT2G22860.1,AT2G23010.1,AT2G23560.1,AT2G24210.1,AT2G24850.1,AT2G26390.1,AT2G26400.2,AT2G26400.1,AT2G26740.1,AT2G27130.1,AT2G27310.1,AT2G27385.1,AT2G27660.1,AT2G27690.1,AT2G28400.1,AT2G28890.1,AT2G29290.1,AT2G29290.2,AT2G29300.1,AT2G29310.2,AT2G29450.1,AT2G29710.1,AT2G29750.1,AT2G30100.1,AT2G30360.1,AT2G30550.2,AT2G30830.1,AT2G32090.1,AT2G32160.2,AT2G32380.1,AT2G32487.2,AT2G32487.3,AT2G32510.1,AT2G33780.1,AT2G34180.1,AT2G34490.1,AT2G34600.1,AT2G34810.1,AT2G34940.1,AT2G35000.1,AT2G35960.1,AT2G36330.1,AT2G36380.1,AT2G37620.2,AT2G37710.1,AT2G37790.1,AT2G37950.1,AT2G38400.1,AT2G38400.2,AT2G38750.1,AT2G38760.1,AT2G39030.1,AT2G39330.3,AT2G39420.1,AT2G39770.2,AT2G40530.1,AT2G40750.1,AT2G41660.1,AT2G41835.1,AT2G41990.1,AT2G42760.1,AT2G42900.1,AT2G43520.1,AT2G43530.1,AT2G43535.1,AT2G43550.1,AT2G44578.1,AT2G44840.1,AT2G45010.1,AT2G45930.1,AT2G46100.1,AT2G46100.2,AT2G46400.1,AT2G46510.1,AT2G47130.1,AT3G01513.1,AT3G01930.2,AT3G02230.1,AT3G02510.1,AT3G02570.1,AT3G03480.1,AT3G03820.1,AT3G03840.1,AT3G04480.1,AT3G05830.1,AT3G06130.1,AT3G07010.1,AT3G07500.1,AT3G07540.1,AT3G09010.1,AT3G09010.2,AT3G09035.1,AT3G09260.1,AT3G09490.1,AT3G10260.1,AT3G11010.1,AT3G11340.1,AT3G11402.1,AT3G12145.1,AT3G12610.1,AT3G14050.1,AT3G14840.2,AT3G15570.1,AT3G15760.1,AT3G15790.1,AT3G15950.1,AT3G16250.1,AT3G16370.1,AT3G16400.2,AT3G16420.1,AT3G16420.3,AT3G16460.1,AT3G16470.1,AT3G16470.2,AT3G17640.1,AT3G17810.1,AT3G17860.1,AT3G18000.1,AT3G18050.1,AT3G18710.1,AT3G19000.1,AT3G19580.1,AT3G19850.1,AT3G20390.1,AT3G20600.1,AT3G20820.1,AT3G21220.2,AT3G21640.1,AT3G22160.1,AT3G22760.2,AT3G22960.1,AT3G23880.1,AT3G25070.1,AT3G25670.1,AT3G25700.1,AT3G25760.1,AT3G25770.1,AT3G25780.1,AT3G25882.1,AT3G26200.1,AT3G26210.1,AT3G26450.1,AT3G26690.1,AT3G28220.1,AT3G28480.1,AT3G28550.1,AT3G28740.1,AT3G29240.2,AT3G29240.1,AT3G29400.1,AT3G44190.1,AT3G44720.1,AT3G44860.1,AT3G44940.1,AT3G45140.1,AT3G45140.2,AT3G46640.2,AT3G46700.1,AT3G47050.1,AT3G47090.1,AT3G47820.1,AT3G48350.1,AT3G48640.2,AT3G50280.1,AT3G50440.1,AT3G50470.1,AT3G50760.1,AT3G50800.1,AT3G51090.1,AT3G51350.1,AT3G51450.1,AT3G51890.1,AT3G51910.1,AT3G52430.1,AT3G52470.1,AT3G52910.1,AT3G55110.1,AT3G55250.1,AT3G55970.1,AT3G55970.2,AT3G56400.1,AT3G56710.1,AT3G56710.2,AT3G57460.1,AT3G57480.2,AT3G57700.1,AT3G58070.1,AT3G59050.1,AT3G60220.1,AT3G60420.1,AT3G61920.1,AT3G62420.1,AT3G62750.7,AT3G63440.1,AT4G00400.1,AT4G00500.1,AT4G00955.1,AT4G01070.1,AT4G01080.1,AT4G01370.1,AT4G01460.1,AT4G01580.1,AT4G02220.1,AT4G02360.1,AT4G02380.3,AT4G03070.1,AT4G03190.1,AT4G04630.1,AT4G04695.1,AT4G04900.1,AT4G06744.1,AT4G08685.1,AT4G08870.1,AT4G09560.1,AT4G10120.5,AT4G10290.1,AT4G10390.1,AT4G11000.1,AT4G11310.1,AT4G11320.1,AT4G11320.2,AT4G11911.1,AT4G12970.1,AT4G13040.7,AT4G13110.1,AT4G13395.1,AT4G13410.2,AT4G13410.1,AT4G13820.1,AT4G13860.1,AT4G14220.1,AT4G14390.2,AT4G15210.1,AT4G15210.3,AT4G15210.4,AT4G15260.1,AT4G15440.1,AT4G15630.1,AT4G15765.1,AT4G16590.1,AT4G16760.1,AT4G16760.2,AT4G17460.1,AT4G17470.1,AT4G17470.3,AT4G17470.4,AT4G17470.2,AT4G18197.1,AT4G18250.1,AT4G18253.1,AT4G18440.1,AT4G18670.1,AT4G18910.1,AT4G19660.2,AT4G19660.1,AT4G21500.1,AT4G21830.2,AT4G21830.1,AT4G22305.1,AT4G22530.2,AT4G23220.1,AT4G23470.1,AT4G23570.3,AT4G23610.1,AT4G23810.1,AT4G23870.1,AT4G23890.1,AT4G24340.1,AT4G24350.4,AT4G24350.1,AT4G24660.2,AT4G24830.1,AT4G24940.1,AT4G25070.1,AT4G25780.1,AT4G25960.1,AT4G26070.1,AT4G26520.4,AT4G26530.1,AT4G26940.1,AT4G27240.2,AT4G27410.2,AT4G27860.1,AT4G28230.1,AT4G28300.1,AT4G28480.1,AT4G28780.1,AT4G29700.1,AT4G30230.1,AT4G30450.1,AT4G30460.1,AT4G30530.1,AT4G30720.1,AT4G32870.1,AT4G33050.3,AT4G34380.1,AT4G34710.2,AT4G35160.1,AT4G35180.2,AT4G35180.1,AT4G35310.2,AT4G36110.1,AT4G36950.1,AT4G37410.1,AT4G37640.1,AT4G38770.1,AT4G39030.1,AT5G01610.1,AT5G01840.1,AT5G01850.2,AT5G01850.1,AT5G01900.1,AT5G01960.1,AT5G02760.1,AT5G02940.1,AT5G03150.1,AT5G03204.1,AT5G03350.1,AT5G03995.1,AT5G05590.1,AT5G05600.1,AT5G05600.2,AT5G05890.1,AT5G06860.1,AT5G06870.1,AT5G07010.1,AT5G08790.1,AT5G10300.1,AT5G10480.1,AT5G10930.1,AT5G12950.1,AT5G13220.1,AT5G13220.7,AT5G16030.2,AT5G16170.1,AT5G17000.2,AT5G17060.1,AT5G17490.1,AT5G18020.1,AT5G18030.1,AT5G18080.1,AT5G19090.3,AT5G19100.1,AT5G19110.1,AT5G19190.1,AT5G19240.1,AT5G19980.1,AT5G20900.1,AT5G21960.1,AT5G22060.1,AT5G22545.1,AT5G22560.1,AT5G22570.1,AT5G22630.1,AT5G23820.1,AT5G24210.1,AT5G24530.1,AT5G24770.1,AT5G24770.2,AT5G24780.2,AT5G24780.1,AT5G25010.1,AT5G26260.1,AT5G26700.1,AT5G26690.1,AT5G27520.1,AT5G28237.1,AT5G35790.1,AT5G36220.1,AT5G37480.1,AT5G38710.1,AT5G40210.1,AT5G40610.1,AT5G41120.3,AT5G41120.1,AT5G42650.1,AT5G42655.2,AT5G42860.1,AT5G43745.1,AT5G44568.1,AT5G44570.3,AT5G44680.1,AT5G44720.1,AT5G44820.1,AT5G45000.1,AT5G45040.1,AT5G45110.1,AT5G45110.2,AT5G45180.1,AT5G45500.3,AT5G45510.2,AT5G46230.1,AT5G46420.1,AT5G48545.2,AT5G49170.1,AT5G50200.1,AT5G51560.1,AT5G51750.1,AT5G52100.1,AT5G52120.1,AT5G52320.1,AT5G52810.1,AT5G52870.1,AT5G53900.2,AT5G54610.1,AT5G54700.2,AT5G54770.1,AT5G54860.1,AT5G55120.1,AT5G56760.1,AT5G57760.1,AT5G57780.1,AT5G58350.1,AT5G58900.1,AT5G59730.1,AT5G60300.2,AT5G60890.1,AT5G61010.2,AT5G61210.1,AT5G62610.1,AT5G62770.1,AT5G63490.1,AT5G63790.1,AT5G63790.2,AT5G64330.1,AT5G64810.1,AT5G65410.1,AT5G66280.1,AT5G66650.1,AT5G66910.1,AT5G67070.1,AT5G67150.1,AT5G67210.1,AT5G67300.1,AT5G67450.1,AT5G67540.1=<django.db.models.fields.CharField>

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i need help to call models

Comment: you try to set `pd.read_csv('UDUBBBBBBBBBBB.csv',sep='\t')` as the model columns?

Comment: i'm import dataframe '''df=pd.read_csv('UDUBBBBBBBBBBB.csv',sep='\t')''',  i try use columns of dataframe. then df.columns it's my model columns

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to use Django to connect to an existing database that has a 700-column table? Or do you plan to create one? I'm wondering if there's time to convince you to use a different schema

Comment: i want connect to an existing database that has a 700-column table

Answer (score 0):

First issue:
As it is right now, your column names cannot have "." ( dot ) in them.

Python interpreter complains because AT1G01560 is unresolved reference.

If you really need the same column name in your database, you can do the following

```
AT1G01560_1 = models.CharField(db_column="AT1G01560.1", max_length=20)
```

Second issue seems to be a problem with extracting the values from your csv files. It seems that your code is creating only one column at the moment with column name "target_id,AT1G01560.3,AT1 .. "

so first, try to correctly parse/extract csv.

Comment: thank you for your answer,     i'm delit "." (dot) my columns but its has same error

Answer (score 0):

Use some other database where you do not need to specify columns while declaring the table.
Use NoSQL database(DynamoDB for example will be a good option)

In DynamoDB you need to specify only the primary keys(primary key is a combination of two fields in this case) and you can send any number of columns in runtime

Comment: thank you for your answer , my django skill's as same as Beginner. but i'm try to  your suggestion